# Commutators and direction of current

Tags: current, motor, dynamo

I just read about commutators and their uses in motors and dynamos. While revising the topic I came across this question:[image]

According to me the answer should be (c). Because:
[image]

In the above diagram of dc motor the direction of current in coil changes from ABCD to DCBA.

[image]

Similarly, in the dc generator shown the direction of current in coil changes from DCBA to ABCD.

But the answer according to the book is (a). This makes me wonder if I missed something in the concept.(or if the given  answer is wrong, which is less likely)

Can somebody please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: A DC generator can potentially use a (3 phase) rectifier rather than a commutator, so the commutator may not be necessary. A rectifier will be far longer lifetime and more reliable. Having said that, A DC brush motor will work fine as a generator, so some generators have mechanical commutators. (Changed my answer to a comment as Heath below has an excellent point, which I upvoted.)

Comment: @JohnD That would make the generator an AC generator.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yeah, true- Kind of a semantic distinction, but you're probably right.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat If BLDC motors can be called DC, then an AC generator packaged with a rectifier can be called DC too.

Comment: @Hearth  That is a stretch.  A DC machine can work as motor or a generator.  A BLDC motor working as a generator is closer to a three-phase ac generator than a DC generator since it generates three pure sinewaves.  But ac generators powering DC buses may make a comeback on ships.  [Onboard DC Grid](http://www04.abb.com/global/seitp/seitp202.nsf/0/292d42e87306453dc12579ad0050a457/$file/12_10_OnboardDCGrid_Technical-Information.pdf)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat My point is that calling a BLDC motor DC is equally as much a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

When using it as a generator, the commutator isn't responsible for changing the direction of the current *in the coil itself*. The coil current changes direction just because that's how it physically works; the job of the commutator in this case is to 'undo' that direction change so that the output current stays in the same direction.

That said, don't feel bad. I would have picked c) as well; it's only your mentioning that a) is the correct answer that got me thinking enough to make this realization. It's a tricky question.